# Initialization control's property without repainting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm creating a control, and adding a property (control's look depends on it). How can I set this property:

1. I can't set the property in form constructor immediatly after `InitializeComponent()` call. In this case user will see two frames of form initialization: the first — after `InitializeComponent()`, and the second — after property setting, that invoke control's redrawing. Bad.
2. Also, I can't mark my propperty with BrowsableAttribute, cause a type of the property, is my own class, that can't be configurated in «properties window». Аlso bad.

So, how could I inicialize the property between `form1.SuspendLayout()` and `form1.ResumeLayout(false)`?

---

Ideally, I would like to have possibility to write a code directly in a respective field of «properties window». For example  I would write `new MyClass(param1, param2)`, if type of the property is MyClass.

Comment: If the property can't be set in the property window why did you make it and why is the control dependent on it?

Comment: This cannot be a real problem.  Painting only happens after the native window for the control is created.  Which happens well after the form constructor has finished running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't force the controll to redraw on property change. It's not necessary when you initialize the control and when a user change the property it will be redrawn in the next paint event. If needed the user can call .Refresh() on your control after setting the property to force the redraw manually.